# Default NSRecessedBezelStyle NSButton visual bug?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I have a basic `NSRecessedBezelStyle` `NSButton` added via IB to an `NSView`. Why is the font messed up in its unselected state? Is this normal?

[image]

As you can see, when pushed the recessed button looks fine, but unpressed it's solid black with no shadow. Am I missing something really obvious somewhere? I tried messing around with `setAttributedTitle` and `setAttributedAlternateTitle` but that yielded odd results with the push on push off mechanic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behavior for NSRecessedBezelStyle with the default "Push On Push Off" Type, bezeled in On state, plain text in OFF, additionally you can change the Type so the bezel is only displayed when hovering, here is the code to make it gray.

```
NSMutableDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];                
[attrsDictionary setObject:[NSColor grayColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
[attrsDictionary setObject:[NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];      
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init] autorelease];
[paragraph setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
[attrsDictionary setObject:paragraph forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];    
NSAttributedString *str = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Button" attributes:attrsDictionary] autorelease];
[button setAttributedTitle:str];
```

Comment: So what would be the best way to set the off state?

Comment: best for what ? the way state is set on NSButtons is setState:

Comment: This doesn't make sense. In interface builder the style looks correct. It's only when I build. Why would a default element that looks identical in every other app have some particular setup for the styling?

Comment: Would you kindly explain to me how I would replace the default black when the button is `Off` and make it a light shade of gray? If I try to use `setAttributedTitle:` with nothing but the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` set it breaks the entire control. Do I have to write my own NSControl just to get this to behave?

Comment: Unfortunately NSButton does not have the nice methods like UIButton's setTitleColor:forState: , maybe eventually that will trickle down from iOS to OS too, for now i added a example in my code